# IdentityServer gets into infinite loop of authentication

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have the following client set up in IdentityServer:

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "My web application",
    Enabled = true,
    ClientId = "mywebapp",
    ClientSecrets = new List<ClientSecret>
    {
        new ClientSecret("somesecret")
    },

    Flow = Flows.Hybrid,

    ClientUri = "https://app.mydomain.com",

    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "oob://localhost/wpfclient",
        "http://localhost:2672/",
        "https://app.mydomain.com"
    }
}
```

And it is hosted online, let's say `https://auth.mydomain.com/core`.

Trying to modify the [MVC OWIN Client (Hybrid)](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/dev/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)) sample client to log-in to the above identity server, in `Startup.cs` I modified the `ClientId`, `ClientSecret` and `RedirectUri` to match the client settings in IdSrv. Now when I try to navigate to a page that requires authorization, I am redirected to IdentityServer's URL. When I log-in, the breakpoint hits at `AuthorizationCodeReceived` notification in the client's `Startup.cs` and then gets into a loop. The browser's status shows:

```
Waiting for localhost...
Waitnig for auth.mydomain.com...
Waiting for localhost...
Waitnig for auth.mydomain.com...
...
```

and so on and never finishes the log-in. Why is this happening? Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most probably this is caused by mixing http and https in redirects. Please use one scheme consistently and check the scheme on browser address-bar.

Comment: wooh, yes that was it! :)

Comment: After a long time with this issue this solved it. Since I'm using Azure I found there was a little add in I could download to force https everytime

Comment: Came across this post and your answer many times in the course of the last day or two trying to figure the redirect loop out. "Can't possibly be that in *my* case" I scoffed.

It was.