# Too many OpenID.nonce cookies cause "Bad Request"

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, identityserver3, openid-connect

I have already gone through links [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1407), [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1124) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795259/too-many-cookies-openidconnect-nonce-cause-error-page-bad-request-request-too) which are related to issue I am having.

I have Silverlight application using IdentiServer3 for authentication and I started having this issue just now when I implemented log out functionality. Note that the issue has nothing to do with Silverlight because login and logout functionality is actually implemented on the server side which is a classic ASP.Net Web form. (.NET 4.5.1)

The application never had logout functionality, so user just used to close the browser so we never encountered this issue before. We have now logout.aspx page and Silverlight application have link to this page.

**Logout.aspx page**

```
public partial class Logout : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        }
        Response.Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx page. This is starting page**

```
public partial class Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
}
```

**OWIN startup class where OpenID connection is configured**

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Default.aspx")
        });

  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"],
            Scope = "openid profile",
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
            RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"],
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {

                    var id = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                    // create new identity
                    var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(id.AuthenticationType);

                    // we want to keep username and subjectid                        
                    var sub = id.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                    var username = id.FindFirst("preferred_username");
                    newIdentity.AddClaim(username);
                    newIdentity.AddClaim(sub);

                    // keep the id_token for logout
                    newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        newIdentity,
                        context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },                    
            }
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. I type web site URL which redirects me to identityserver3 login
   page.
2. I enter credentials and hit login.
3. After successful login I
   get redirected to the web site and  There I click log out.
4. I get logged
   out successfully. Fiddler shows the following calls

   https://idsvr.mydomain.com/identity/connect/endsession?id_token_hint=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   https://idsvr.mydomain.com/identity/logout?id=616dd9a4e4c6a55b0bb27faceb4df8dd
   https://idsvr.mydomain.com/identity/connect/endsessioncallback?sid=xxxxxx
5. I land up on https://idsvr.mydomain.com/identity/logout?id=xxxxxxx page as expected.
6. Now I close the browser ( this step is important)
7. Now type web site URL again which redirects me to identity server login page. ( like Step 1)
8. I enter credentials and hit login.
9. After successful login, IdentityServer makes POST to the web site and web site creates AuthenticationTicket. However, here `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` is false so `Default.aspx` page redirects to IdentityServer. I am already logged in so Indetityserver redirects to client web site and loops continue.

Fiddler shows several round trips from identityServer to web site’s default.aspx page. Each roundtrip keeps adding `OpenIdConnect.nonce.OpenIdConnect` cookie and ultimately i get bad request error because of max request size.

So as suggested in above links I downgraded `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` to `3.0.0` in Client Application.

However, I still get stuck in continuous loop. The only difference is now it does not add new `OpenIdConnect.nonce.OpenIdConnect` cookie for each round trip. Fiddler shows only one cookie for each round trip. However `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` is still false. So I get stuck in continuous loop.

Comment: Sometimes endless loop occurred, when Client uses http, but Server https ( or opposite) . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780627/identityserver-gets-into-infinite-loop-of-authentication

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @bkwdesign yes, i resolved it by adding https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver middleware.

Answer (score 8):

I  had a similar issue with my asp.net mvc application . After some Research i found that there is a bug in Microsoft's Owin implementation for System.Web. The one that is being used when running Owin applications on IIS. Which is what probably 99% of us do, if we're using the new Owin-based authentication handling with ASP.NET MVC5.

The bug makes cookies set by Owin mysteriously disappear on some occasions.

This middleware is a fix for that bug. Simple add it before any cookie handling middleware and it will preserve the authentication cookies.

```
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
```

Here is the link in detail 
https://github.com/KentorIT/owin-cookie-saver

Comment: I've spent days trying to debug a situation where our Owin middleware was authorising a user but the authentication cookie was going missing.  I installed the above NuGet package and now it just works!  Thanks for this.

Comment: @Narendra i tried installing nuget package `Kentor.OwinCookieSaver` but i am getting error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Kentor.OwinCookieSaver 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0 `

Answer (score 1):

What solved the problem for me was using AdamDotNet's Custom OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler to delete old nonce cookies.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51671887/4058784